# broadcast receiver for ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG not getting called

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm having a broadcast reciever:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mediaReceiver = new MediaChangeReceiver(this);
```

and i'm adding filters to it

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
context.registerReceiver(mediaReceiver, filter);
```

and I have listener to listen for that calls

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "headset plug has been called");
                break;

            case BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED has been called");
                break;

            case AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED has been called");
                break;

            default:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "default been called");
                break;
        }
    }
```

but when I'm connecting BT headphones (after the broadcast receiver has been called)
I don't get any of the broadcast receiver intents called

here is the full broadcast receiver class

```
public class MediaChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MediaChangeReceiver.class.getName();
    private MediaChangeListener mListener;

    public MediaChangeReceiver(MediaChangeListener listener) {
    super();
    mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "headset plug has been called");
                break;

            case BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED has been called");
                break;

            case AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED has been called");
                break;

            default:
                //do something
                Log.e ("test", "default been called");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

here is my intent in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaChangeReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

what am I doing wrong? can anyone help?

Comment: Could you provide full code of the class where you create and register receiver?

Comment: Did you registered for the broadcast in the service?. If yes, did you add the `intent-filter` to your service?.

Comment: @Romman i'm note sure i understand 100% what you mean, 
I'm having the BroadcastReceiver for the MediaChangeReceiver called in a class and I show here in example how I add filters to it , and than I have the MediaChangeReceiver class separately, could you explain again what you mean ?

Comment: @MikhailGuliaev it's more or less what i shared here I can share the full one it's almost the same

Comment: What I want to mean is "Your receiver should in a service". In the manifest file where you defined your service should include the `intent-filter`. Thus when you register for the user media session actions, based on the registered action the broadcast will receive data.

Comment: @Romman yes i can add here the section to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was missing the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
```

and the app needs to ask that permission
I couldn't find a way to make that work without getting that Bluetooth permission

if someone found a way to check when Bluetooth is connected without asking for Bluetooth permission please write in this question thread

Comment: You can ask for this as optional permission. android:required="false" Make sure to test it out and add error handler so your app will still work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the way the intent filters are defined in the manifest file. You need to remove the package name prefix from the action names in the  tag.

Try modifying the intent filter like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaChangeReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: hi @Taslim Oseni that didn't help

Comment: Do you have permissions set up in your manifest file? From what I can see, you need BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions for Bluetooth related intents to work.